# How can I use ALAssetsLibrary in unit test?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode4, alassetslibrary

I wonder how I can use ALAssetsLibrary in my unit test in Xcode 4? 
Right now I get "Data unavailable" when calling ALAssetsLibrary.

Answer (score 0):

Plug in a phone and run the test target on the phone. Doing so is the same as running your app on the phone, but instead of the normal app target, run your test target.